# how do i get the latitude and longitude from google maps places api object?

Tags: google-maps, vuejs2, google-places-api, vuetify.js

How do I get my lat and lon coordinates from my address data in google maps places api?

template

```
      <vuetify-google-autocomplete
        outline
        id="address"
        types="geocode"
        append-icon="map"
        placeholder="WHERE"
        label="postcode or city"
        v-model="location"
        v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
      >
      </vuetify-google-autocomplete>
```

script:

```
  methods: {
    /**
    * When the location found
    * @param {Object} addressData Data of the found location
    * @param {Object} placeResultData PlaceResult object
    * @param {String} id Input container ID
    */
    getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData, id) {
        this.address = addressData;
        console.log(addressData)
    },

}
```

i get an addressData object in my console like this:

```
{...}
administrative_area_level_1: (...)
country: (...)
latitude: 39.1910983
locality: (...)
longitude: (...)
name: (...)
photos: (...)
place_id: (...)
postal_code: (...)
```

console.log(addressData.latitude) gets a "Cannot read property 'latitude' of null"

Comment: Where did you get the `addressData`, is it coming from REST API or another source? Perhaps, the method you call to get that `addressData` is promise, you have to wait for it to be resolved first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using [Vuetify Google Autocomplete](https://github.com/MadimetjaShika/vuetify-google-autocomplete). You get a null value if you don't select a place from the list of Autocomplete suggestions.

Try adding the code below in your `getAddressData` function:

```
getAddressData: function(addressData, placeResultData, id) {
  this.address = addressData;
  if (addressData !== null) {
    console.log("lat: " + addressData.latitude);
    console.log("lng: " + addressData.longitude);
  }
}
```

Then follow these steps:

1. Type "california" into the text field
2. Select the first option, "California, USA" from the list of place predictions
3. Then open up the console and you should see the following output:

   lat: 36.778261
    
    lng: -119.41793239999998

Hope this helps!